# Extensive L&F modification

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I want to use multiple L&Fs in my application, but that makes translating my application very complicated, due to differences between various L&Fs...

So I thought to myself, why don't I download L&F I want to use and then edit them in a way they all have, e.g. same key for same component name parts, making translating it during runtime far more simple...

It'd like to use, for one, Nimbus L&F, but I don't know where to find the it's source code (or files) that I can edit...

I know it's included in newest Java (which I have, both JRE and SDK), but I just don't know where to find it... Google just keeps showing pages on how to set it...

Comment: How does the L&F influence the "translation" of your application? I have personnally developped an application that can switch L&F and Language at runtime without troubles.

Comment: Well, some components, like JFileChooser have predefined looks, which contains several strings. I'd like to be able to change that strings during runtime. That is possible, but I was told that different L&Fs have different keys for them, so I'd have to write access code for each L&F separately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the complete source for the JDK is at the path:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\src.zip

and within that zip the path to nimbus source is:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\src.zip\javax\swing\plaf\nimbus\

Of course this is windows only, but *mix systems shouldnt differ in this respective apart from replacing *C:\Program Files\* with the appropriate corresponding one

Comment: Thanks, I found it... But I'm having problems again...

You wouldn't know which classes contain keys for strings that are painted, would you?

Comment: @IvanKarlovic Im not sure off the top of my head but look at the documention is should show you the package(s) name